# On dimension of algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $m\leq n$.  Suppose $\pi:\mathbb{A}^n\to \mathbb{A}^m$ is map which sends $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\to (a_1,\ldots,a_m)$.   If $V$ is an affine algebraic set, then is it true that $\dim(V)\geq \dim(\overline{\pi(V)})$.

My attempt:  If $V$ is affine variety, then $\pi|_V$ is a dominant map.  Thus we get a corresponding injection of the function fields and hence by comparing cardinality of transcendence base we arrive at $\dim(V)\geq \dim(\overline{\pi(V)})$.

If $V$ is not irreducible, then $\dim(V)=\max(\dim(V_i))$ where $V=\bigcup_i V_i$ and $V_i$ are closed irreducible sets.  Thus, we get that $\dim(V)=\dim(V_j)\geq \dim(\overline{\pi(V_j)})$ for some $j$.  I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: Note that $\pi(\bigcup V_i) = \bigcup \pi(V_i)$. Can you apply the closure operator to both sides?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Greg Martin for the hint.

We observe that $\dim(\pi(V))=\dim(\pi(\cup_i V_i))=\dim(\cup_i \pi(V_i))$.

Now assuming $\dim(\cup_i \pi(V_i))$ is finite, any chain of irreducible closed sets in $\cup_i \pi(V_i)$ must be contained in some $\pi(V_j)$.

Thus, $\dim(\cup_i \pi(V_i))=\dim(\pi(V_j))=\dim(\overline{\pi(V_j)})\leq \dim(V_j)\leq \dim(V)$.